# Migrations doesn't work in dotnet with postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm working with dotnet CLI. IDE - VS Code.

It is a 3 layered project

- SuperMarket.Api.Employees
- SuperMarket.Data.Employees
- SuperMarket.Service.Employees.

using these Nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version=7.0.0,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version=7.0.0, 
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL Version="7.0.0",
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version=7.0.0
```

When I try to execute this code from `SuperMarket.Data.Employees` layer:

```
dotnet ef migrations add addColoums -s ..\SuperMarket.Api.Employees\
```

I got this error in terminal

> The Entity Framework tools version '6.0.10' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.0'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes. See https://aka.ms/AAc1fbw for more information.
> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.
> Unable to create an object of type 'EmployeeDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

`Program.cs` (db-related only)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
.AddFluentValidation (x=>
     { 
      x.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
      x.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
     }
    );

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SuperMarketDb")));

// var logger =  builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILogger<SuperMarketExceptionMiddleware>>();
// builder.Services.AddSingleton(logger);


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors("corsapp");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMiddleware<SuperMarketExceptionMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`EmployeeDbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SuperMarket.Data.Employees.Models;

namespace SuperMarket.Data.Employees.Data
{
    public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        // protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        // {
        //   modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSalary>()
        //     .HasOne<Employee>(x=>x.Employees).WithMany(p=>p.employeeSalary).HasForeignKey;
        // }
        
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
        public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
        public DbSet<SalaryComponents>SalaryComponents {get; set;}
        public DbSet<EmployeeSalary> EmployeeSalary{get; set;}
    }
}
```

How can I resolve the problem? Did I miss anything?

Connection strings are proper.

Comment: Have you updated the EF tools to the latest version? If not, you should be able to do so by running `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef` from a command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by updating ef tools globally using

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

command and commenting out the below portion while doing migration and updation. Later I uncommented it.

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
.AddFluentValidation (x=>
     { 
      x.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
      x.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
     }
    );
```